# How to execute Gremlin against OrientDB using orientjs?

Tags: node.js, orientdb, gremlin

In Node, what is the correct way to execute [Gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/gremlin.html) queries against a database?

My current attempt using the [Official Node OrientDB Driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/orientjs):

```or-tag-here
const { ODatabase } = require('orientjs');
const db = new ODatabase({...});
db.query('g.V()')
  .then(console.log, console.error);
```

And I get:

```
OrientDB.RequestError: 
  Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.g.V()
  DB name="mynevo"
at child.Operation.parseError 
  (.../orientjs/lib/transport/binary/protocol33/operation.js:864:13)
```

However, when I execute `g.V()` in the web interface, it works perfectly.

Clearly the Node driver or the server assumes the query is supposed to be SQL. Is there a way to tell it to be Gremlin, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to execute gremlin command using

```

```
db.query('g.V()', { 
        language : "gremlin", 
        class : "com.orientechnologies.orient.graph.gremlin.OCommandGremlin"
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
```

```

Comment: Thanks! Additionally, do you know how to inject parameters? Whatever I try, it says 'No such property: p1 for class: Script17'... For example: `g.V().has('name', p1)` with `{params: { p1: 'Alan' }}`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest way to execute a gremlin query against OrientDB is to use the REST API (port 2480, NOT binary port 2424).
It is one call, I suggest trying it out first in postman.

[POST] http://:2480/command//gremlin

Then the request body can look like this:

```
{
    "command": "g.V().has('name', 'marko')"
}
```

Pass the OrientDB credentials as basic auth

In NodeJS/JavaScript simply use superagent or a similar module to call the REST API. Then analyze the results which are returned as JSON.

See also:
https://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html

Look under Command section