# Error while executing gremlin query on OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

The following query when run from OrientDB studio gives error.

**Query**:
    `g.V('userId', 'SDWEQS').repeat(out()).until(has('organizationId','org1'));`

**Error**:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.out() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: put(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), get(java.lang.String), wait(), any(), dump(), wait(long)

I tried running the query using the OrientJs Node app but get the same error. I created the same graph on gremlin server and this query works there.

My question is whether orientdb supports `repeat()`? Please suggest alternatives to make the above query work.

Comment: Hi, have you gave a look at it?http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/.

Comment: Yes @MichelaBonizzi the above query I ran on a gremlin server and it runs fine. The problem is only when I run it against orientdb.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Orientdb version we are using is  2.2.21

Comment: If you execute the same query against orientdb database by gremlin console, does it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is that OrientDB is only supporting gremlin queries of Tinkerpop 2.x. And "repeat()" wasn't part of 2.x. I will have to rework the query to use "loop()" instead.

Comment: Do you have a source on this?

Answer (score -1):

See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775290/1211805

Basically just use the OrientDB REST API (port 2480)